# devise redirects to login after login

Tags: devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

When a user logins into my page it redirects them to the sign-in page without error. It actually logs them in but for some reason it won't redirect to the user's show page.

I have this, which as worked in other cases, in my application controller:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
    user_url(user)
end
```

here is the link to my repo https://github.com/samwat2/Ships-Project

I'm new to rails and I'm not quiet sure this isn't working! When it has before...

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your repo, you added the two custom fields :first_name and :last_name to the registration form, and you validate the presence of those attributes. If you have added these validations after creating some users, and try to login with a user that misses some of these fields, devise will encounter a validation error when saving the user and redirect back to the login form, even though the authentication itself was successful.

Try making the users valid by filling the missing attributes, and the login should behave again as intended.